# What to do when a minimal form of the example code doesn't show the same error message?

Tags: support, questions

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861193/operator-for-custom-object-illegal-for-class) question<sup>1</sup>, I have a code that in its initial form displays only the last two lines of the current form of the error message, which made me ask the question.

However, following the suggestion to provide MINIMAL, reproducible copy expressing the same behaviour I got the present state of the error message.

Long story short, whatever I do the score is negative, even I've followed all the remarks and suggestions. What should I do to reverse the negative votes?

---

<sup>1. Follow through the edits to get more clear picture.</sup>

Comment: "What should I do to reverse the negative votes?" - if it is (now) a good question that benefits others, you just wait. Its not like there is a time limit on the ability to upvote a question or answer, I'm still getting regular upvotes for an answer I posted years ago. Time will heal everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question in its original form seems to have been unanswerable due to lack of a minimal example showing the error. Probably because of that it was downvoted.

Sometime later you fixed it and a few people upvoted it. There's nothing forcing the original downvoters to come back and even if they did nobody can make them upvote the question now it's improved.

There's nothing much else you can do to fix the downvotes now. However now that you know what to do your next question is less likely to get downvotes, that's all you can really take away from this.

Comment: lesson learnt, no question about it. I just wonder why there is no reciprocity between up and down vote, after there is an action correcting their indications and practically negating the negative votes. But it is probably more related to each and every individual.

Comment: You wasted people's time when they read the question in the first place. That you corrected it later does not put them in the same position they would have been had you written it properly in the first place as it's taken them twice as long to figure out what you wanted. Downvotes therefore are not always reversed even by people who reread the question. Accept, learn and move on is all you can do.